# How to evaluate multi-variable integrals such as $\int xy\, dx\,dy$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals

How are integrals with two variables calculated?

Like $$\int xy\, dx\,dy$$

I'm new in multivariable calculus so please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit confused about your notation. The normal way to denote what you intended is use the number of integrals corresponding to the number of variables (in your case 2), which in LaTeX can be done with `\iint` for 2 or `\iiint` for 3 variables.

The usual idea is to compute double integral as an integral of an integral, e.g.
$$
\begin{split}
\iint xy\ dx dy
 &= \int \left[\int xy dy\right] dx \\
 &= \int x \left[\int y dy\right] dx \\
 &= \int x \left[\frac{y^2}{2}\right] dx \\
 &= \frac{y^2}{2} \int x dx \\
 &= \frac{x^2 y^2}{4} + C
\end{split}
$$

Now that you understand that double integral is really an integral of an integral, the $\iint$ notation also makes sense.

Note that this goes $y$-first, but going $x$-first would not change things. Formally, you need Fubini's Theorem to know that though...

**UPDATE**

As is explicitly pointed out in the comments, $C$ in case of one-variable integration amounts to a constant, here would have the form $C(y) + K(x)$.

Comment: Actually I just rushed to ask here, I should have done a little bit of home working before asking here....thanks btw

Comment: An indefinite double integral has a much more general $C$ than your notation may suggest. Since $\int ydy=\frac12y^2+f(x)$ for some function $f$, the final result of the calculation is $\frac14x^2y^2+F(x)+G(y)$ for functions $F,\,G$.

Comment: @J.G. +1, was thinking to add this explicitly or not, opted against it. With your comment, added an update.